# Defining giving a warning in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to declare a debug flag is on or off in these both ways:

```
#define inDebugMode true
```

or

```
const bool inDebugMode = true;
```

The compiler in Visual Studio 2010 always gives a warning:

```
warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
```

Why is that? How can I declare it correctly?

Comment: Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t66728h(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without seeing the code, I suspect you have the following construct:

```
if (inDebugMode)
{
}
```

which will always be `true`, hence the warning.

Recommend using the preprocessor instead of `if`:

```
#define inDebugMode 1

#if inDebugMode
#endif
```

This will remove the warning and prevent the debugging code being compiled when unrequired. Note you can also specify the value of a macro via the compiler switch [`/D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx):

```
cl.exe /DinDebugMode=1 ...
```

but you need to ensure you rebuild all sources if you choose the command line option, not just the changed sources.

Comment: use `#if` not `#ifdef` if you wish that to be `false` when you change the value to 0.

Answer (score 3):

This warning is not for the definition but for the use of it.
lets say you write in your code something like:

```
if (inDebugMode)
{
    //your code
}
```

when the compiler encounter it (after the precompile in case of the define) this is always true and there it thinks the "if" is not needed. that's way it's only a warning not a error.
in order to avoid it you can do like that:

```
#define inDebugMode 1
//some code
#if inDebugMode
    //your code you only want to run in debug
#endif
```

this way if you not in debug all the code in the "#if" section will be omitted by the precompiler and the compiler wouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like preprocessor directives and would like to use the const bool, then you may disable "warning C4127" directly (Project Properties / C/C++ / Advanced / Disable Specific Warnings / type "4127").